# Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros2 (404 not found)

Tags: ros2, ros-humble

I am trying to upgrade my packages but when I run `apt upgrade` I am getting the following error:

```
E: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-humble-rviz2/ros-humble-rviz2_11.2.7-1jammy.20230814.171234_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2605:bc80:3010::134 80]
```

Did the gpg keys expired or got changed? I checked the github repo and the last change was 2 years ago, so I am not sure what is happening.

Any ideas?

BTW: I am using ubuntu 22.04 + ROS Humble

**EDIT 1:**

`apt update` output:

```
$ sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Hit:2 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu jammy InRelease                                                                                                          
Get:3 https://nvidia.github.io/libnvidia-container/stable/ubuntu18.04/amd64  InRelease [1.484 B]                                                                        
Hit:4 https://repo.steampowered.com/steam stable InRelease                                                                                                              
Hit:5 https://updates.signal.org/desktop/apt xenial InRelease                                                                                                           
Hit:6 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu jammy InRelease                                                                                      
Hit:7 https://app.eduvpn.org/linux/v4/deb focal InRelease                                                                                                               
Hit:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease                                                                                                                  
Hit:9 http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu jammy InRelease                                                                                              
Hit:10 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/pipewire-debian/pipewire-upstream/ubuntu jammy InRelease                
Hit:11 https://repo.vaticle.com/repository/apt trusty InRelease                           
Hit:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease     
Hit:13 http://packages.osrfoundation.org/gazebo/ubuntu-stable jammy InRelease
Hit:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Hit:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Fetched 1.484 B in 1s (1.942 B/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
73 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
```

**Solution**

I had to manually delete the apt cache. I tried running `apt clean` but it didn't work.

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

Comment: No, I don't think so: I believe [this](https://discourse.ros.org/t/ros-gpg-key-expiration-incident/20669) describes the last time that happened (and provides a solution). So you can certainly try that solution but I'd be checking that you can actually ping that server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you just need to run a "sudo apt update" to get the latest versions of available Debians.

The file name you referenced does not currently exist on the server - but a version with the later build date code of 20230822 does exist - so I think your apt cache is out of date.

Comment: I did run `sudo apt update` before trying to upgrade.
I am only having problems with ros packages. 
If I run `apt upgrade --fix-missing` it upgrades the non-ros packages

Comment: I would suggest looking closely at the output/errors from your "apt update" command - something is going wrong there because the package you're trying to download is an older version, so the cache doesn't match what's actually on the server.

Comment: There is nothing out of the ordinary in the apt update output. I updated the question with the output.
By the way, I tried doing the same process from two different locations to make sure it is nothing related to my network setup.

Comment: Ok, I solved it. I manually deleted all the apt caches. I tried using `apt clean` but it didn't work. I updated the question with the solution.

Comment: Thanks for the help!